# Refresh external data when component params change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useAsync (from react-use) to fetch external data.
The relevant code looks something like this

```
export const MyComponent: FC = () => {
     const {param1,param2} = useParams as {
           Param1: string,
           Param2: string
       }
      const(value,loading,error) = useAsync(async():Promise<MyData> => {getSomeData..});
     ...
```

}

If this page routes to itself, but updating the parameters (param1 and param2), then the external data doesn't get re-fetched.
In other words, the useAsync line doesn't get re executed

What is the way of getting the external data re-loaded when the page params change?

Comment: You can use the useEffect hook to watch the param values: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this;

```
      const(value,loading,error) = useAsync(async():Promise<MyData> => {getSomeData..}, [param1, param2]);
```